Why am i not able to install admin for orgs on my hyperledger frabric test-network setup?
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer


this is my config.yaml file for the msp for org1

richmond@RICHMAN-MAKAFUI:/mnt/c/Users/USER/fabric-samples/test-network$ openssl x509 -in /mnt/c/Users/USER/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/cert.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            01:1d:2f:41:c4:c9:60:2a:58:69:ad:f1:12:ce:0d:60:18:17:f6:e3
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, ST = North Carolina, L = Durham, O = org1.example.com, CN = ca.org1.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 27 08:23:00 2024 GMT
            Not After : Sep 27 09:08:00 2025 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = North Carolina, O = Hyperledger, OU = client, CN = admin
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:20:39:14:38:83:c9:d2:35:ab:8f:a9:1b:46:4c:
                    62:a2:fb:cd:4c:c4:b8:2b:03:38:18:e1:36:63:6d:
                    53:8d:15:38:28:85:f6:ad:48:d1:af:40:49:d4:9e:
                    4c:0b:b0:bc:68:a0:15:7b:a0:fb:65:61:25:09:c9:
                    5b:ac:07:5a:e2
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                1D:9F:E7:6A:21:30:4B:3D:1D:49:EB:39:89:6B:CB:C5:8E:D0:B0:37
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                6B:16:6C:7C:67:94:88:3C:F4:40:59:81:A4:D7:B5:2A:6E:86:E6:1F
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:RICHMAN-MAKAFUI
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
        30:45:02:21:00:81:8d:b4:3b:8a:2f:43:85:07:e3:67:aa:e2:
        8b:b9:9e:13:8f:a2:7c:1a:82:ed:39:31:82:6b:ee:7e:f9:df:
        65:02:20:00:fa:15:18:1f:97:35:bd:a4:af:37:61:36:6d:a8:
        d4:cd:44:05:85:58:6f:99:6e:c3:06:f4:a0:dc:c8:86:ca

however the OU is still set to Client and not admin

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
